# How to resize existing height and width of pdf page size?

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I am generating a PDF from HTML using a library. For some pages in PDF the height and width is coming as that for standard A4(595 x 842 pt') page. How to resize the height and width for these pages?

Comment: Maybe change some parameters of framework class you use while generating pdf.

Comment: Can you tell us which library you are using?

Comment: For html to pdf I am using HiQPdf and for xls to pdf spire.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageSize = PdfPageSize.A6;
```

This uses HiQPdf

Comment: I put A6 as an example just switch to the size you want